# Camel-Kafka Integration Issue

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am trying Camel-Kafka integration.
I have two queues :
**`queue1`** and **`queue2`**.

There are three routes :

1. **Route1** puts a list of two messages in **`queue1`** (It should do it only **once**).
2. **Route2** reads the list from **`queue1`**, splits it, and puts the individual messages in **`queue2`**
3. **Route3** reads the messages from **`queue2`** and just prints it.

The code is as follows :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CamelListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new CamelListRoute());
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        context.stop();
    }
}

class CamelListRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {


        //Route1, expected to run once
        from("timer://timerName?repeatCount=1").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                List<String> inOrderList = new ArrayList<String>();
                inOrderList.add("1");
                inOrderList.add("2");
                exchange.getIn().setBody(inOrderList, ArrayList.class);
            }
        })
        .to("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue1");


        //Route2
        from("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue1&groupId=testing&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
        .split()
        .body().process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("2nd Route : " + (exchange.getIn().getBody().toString()));
            }
        })
        .to("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue2");


        //Route3
        from("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue2&groupId=testing&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("3rd Route : " + (exchange.getIn().getBody().toString()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is not working as expected, and there are few issues observed :

1. The first route, which is expected to run only once (**repeatCount=1**), runs continuously, putting the same message in **`queue1`** again and again.
2. The second route reads the messages from **`queue1`**, splits it, but does not put it in **`queue2`**
3. Since second route does not put anything in **`queue2`**, this route does not get any messages.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of things:

1. I hope you are giving Kafka Url like this:  "kafka://localhost:9092?topic=queue1"

note: **kafka://**

2. Providing zookeeper urls for consumers eg: kafka://?topic=queue1&zookeeperConnect=&consumerStreams=1&groupId=testing&autoOffsetReset=**largest**
3. Note in previous point autoOffsetReset value will be **largest** or **smallest** instead of **latest**.

Comment: Yes, I have used the url correctly. The issue got resolved after using exchange.getOut().setBody() to pass the data to next route.

Comment: Ohk, I think you can post the answer. It will be helpful for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud exchange the message.

in processor do something like:

exchng.getOut().setHeader("type", "queue");
exchng.getOut().setBody(exchng.getIn().getBody() );

then could add a choice in the second route, does not require the third route.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first issue of running continuously and putting the same message in queue1 again and again is happening because you are using the same consumer groupId, `groupId=testing` for both your kafka consumers in routes 2 and 3.

Amend the kafka consumers to consume from different groupIds like so and this will ensure that the message is not consumed again and again.

```
//Route2
from("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue1&groupId=testing-queue1&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
```

and

```
//Route3
from("kafka:<ip>:9092?topic=queue2&groupId=testing-queue2&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
```

The other issues of producing to queue2 and consuming from it to print, I think might be due to version incompatibilities. I have used camel-kafka version 2.20.1 (that uses kafka-clients 0.11.0.1 under the hood) and 2.21.0 (that uses kafka-clients 1.0.0 under the hood) and changed the routes to reflect the changes like so and this seems to consume-produce-consume fine.

```
class CamelListRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {


        //Route1, expected to run once
        from("timer://timerName?repeatCount=1").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                List<String> inOrderList = new ArrayList<String>();
                inOrderList.add("1");
                inOrderList.add("2");
                exchange.getIn().setBody(inOrderList, ArrayList.class);
            }
        })
        .to("kafka:queue1?brokers=<ip>:9092");


        //Route2
        from("kafka:queue1?brokers=<ip>:9092&groupId=testing-queue1&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
        .split()
        .body().process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("2nd Route : " + (exchange.getIn().getBody().toString()));
            }
        })
        .to("kafka:queue2?brokers=<ip>:9092");


        //Route3
        from("kafka:queue2?brokers=<ip>:9092&groupId=testing-queue2&autoOffsetReset=latest&consumersCount=1")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("3rd Route : " + (exchange.getIn().getBody().toString()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```